# My JTextArea doesn't work properly

Tags: java, swing

I have the following function that works with a linked list and a text area. Inside this function I have the while loop, it iterates until the list is empty and prints each element into a text area. After this, it removes the first element of the list and it goes back to the while again. The problem that I have is that I have to clear the TextArea after it prints all the elements of the list, but when it removes the first element and reaches the while again it doesn't print anything in the TextArea and I don't know how to fix it

```
public void function() {
        Node e;
        while(!list.isEmpty()) {
            print();
            e = list.getFirst();
            list.remove(e);
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        Iterator<Node> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Node c = (Node)it.next();
            textArea1.append("ID: "+c.ID+"\n");
        }
        textArea1.setText("");
    }
```

Comment: I bet my left shoe that you're blocking the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) ...

Comment: Have you tried putting `textArea1.setText("");` in the `function` method before the `while` look?  This way to will clear the list before it runs over list.  You will probably also want to have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).